# Hooks useEffect and settimeout

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have a problem with the logic of my useEffect, I don't know if I understand it very well ..
i am using redux and when sending a message i set my waitResponse = = true on the reducer and then do that in this useEffect:

```
 const ChatReducer = useSelector(state => state.Chat);
 const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState(false);
 const [hasResponded, setHasResponded] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
    // Notice the change here checking if we have already responded
    // The if statement now surrounds the timeout and the interval
    // This prevents any of these actions from happening once the response  has been made
    setHasResponded(false);
    if (ChatReducer.waitResponse === true && !hasResponded) {
      setIsTyping(true);
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('aeee');
        setHasResponded(true);
        dispatch(wait_end());
        setIsTyping(false);
      }, 3000);
      return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
  }, [ChatReducer.waitResponse, hasResponded]);
```

basically if i send 2 texts in a row it doesn’t enter my timout 2 times just once:

[image]

Comment: It's probably because you set the `hasResponded` flag inside setTimeout callback. Once your callback is executed, the condition above is preventing any subsequent execution (assuming `ChatReducer.waitResponse` is not changed).

Comment: after i send my dispatch(wait_end()); i change waitResponse to false

Comment: and on user send message i change waitresponse to true

Answer (score 0):

Your issue arises because once `hasResponded` is set to `true`, the inner logic of your `useEffect` won't run again for subsequent messages, as it's in the dependency array.

To solve this:

1. Remove `hasResponded` from the `useEffect` dependency array.
2. Use functional updates for state. When setting `hasResponded`, do this:

```js
setHasResponded(prev => !prev);
```

This should ensure that the timeout logic is triggered with every message.